# How to pass multidimensional list or tuple to C# Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, multidimensional-array, asmx

I'm working on a web service that needs to accept a collection with three values of different types. The values are

SkuNumber (integer),
FirstName (string),
LastName (string)

I want the web service to accept a list of 100 instances of these values but am not sure how to go about it. Do I use a multidimensional list or array? Maybe a tuple? Or can I just create a simple class structure and accept a list of that class?

This is all simple enough in a normal application, I'm just not sure how the app calling the web service would pass the data with any of the given options.

Can someone give me some pointers?

Comment: Fwiw, I generally avoid proper multidimensional arrays like the plague: they're somewhat inefficient, have poor compatibility with newer constructs like linq and serialization, and generally cause headaches.

Comment: Is this a WCF service, or a legacy ASMX service?

Comment: It is a legacy ASMX service. It will be called from a java POS type terminal application. The service can be written in WCF is that proves to be a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a shared assembly is not feasible, you can always go with good ol' XML. It may not be the optimal solution and I'm sure plenty of users here will balk at the idea, but it is easy to support and relatively quick to implement, so it really depends on your individual situation and the skill level of the developers responsible for supporting the application.

The benefit to using XML here, is that the calling application can be written in almost any language on almost any platform, as long as it adheres to the XML structure.

The XML string should be easy enough to generate in the calling application, but the biggest downside here is that if you have a ton of data, the processing may take longer than desired -- on both ends of the service.

Here is a working sample if you want to give it a try:

```
 public class Whatever
    {
        public int SkuNumber { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public void HelloWorld(string xmlString)
    {
        //make all the node names + attribute names lowercase, to account for erroneous xml formatting -- leave the values alone though
        xmlString = Regex.Replace(xmlString, @"<[^<>]+>", m => m.Value.ToLower(),RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline);

        var xmlDoc = LoadXmlDocument(xmlString);


        var listOfStuff = new List<Whatever>();

        var rootNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
        foreach(XmlNode xmlNode in rootNode)
        {
            var whatever = new Whatever
                               {
                                   FirstName = xmlNode["first_name"].InnerText,
                                   LastName = xmlNode["last_name"].InnerText,
                                   SkuNumber = Convert.ToInt32(xmlNode["sku_number"].InnerText)
                               };
            listOfStuff.Add(whatever);
        }
    }

    public static XmlDocument LoadXmlDocument(string xmlString)
    {
        //some extra stuff to account for URLEncoded strings, if necessary
        if (xmlString.IndexOf("%3e%") > -1)
            xmlString = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(xmlString);

        xmlString = xmlString.Replace((char)34, '\'').Replace("&", "&amp;").Replace("\\", "");

        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace = false;
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlString);

        return xmlDocument;
    }
```

Your XML would look like this:

```
<stuff_to_track>
<whatever>
    <sku_number>1</sku_number>
    <first_name>jimi</first_name>
    <last_name>hendrix</last_name>
</whatever>
<whatever>
    <sku_number>2</sku_number>
    <first_name>miles</first_name>
    <last_name>davis</last_name>
</whatever>
<whatever>
    <sku_number>3</sku_number>
    <first_name>david</first_name>
    <last_name>sanborn</last_name>
</whatever>
<whatever>
    <sku_number>4</sku_number>
    <first_name>john</first_name>
    <last_name>coltrane</last_name>
</whatever>
</stuff_to_track>
```

I also recommend validating the incoming XML, for both schema and data.

Comment: Thanks kmdsax. I will try this approach. Given the different platforms I think it might be the best fit.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class and accept a list of that class.  Be sure to mark it as [Serializable].

```
[Serializable]   
public class Whatever
{
    public int SkuNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Best practice would be to define the class in an assembly that can be accessed by both the service and the project that calls it.

The trouble with a tuple or a multi-dimensional array is that the data you send doesn't have an inherent identity:  you could stick any old thing in there.  If you have a class, you are indicating that you are sending an Order or an Inquiry or a Coupon or whatever it is you are tracking.  There's a level of meaning that goes along with it.

Comment: Thanks Ann. That is clear enough. I guess I'm still fuzzy on how the calling application would work. They would need to have the same class structure on their side and pass a list of 'Whatever' instances?

Comment: Actually, I see you suggested having the class defined in an assembly accessible to both. Is that the only way, or could they define an identical class on the side of the calling app? I'm just not sure if we have a commonly accessible location available.

Comment: FYI, if this is an ASMX service, then it uses the XML Serializer, which pays little attention to the `[Serializable]` attribute.

Comment: Are you saying that adding [Serializable] isn't necessary and it will be serialized without, or that serialization of the class structure wouldn't be possible in an ASMX?

Comment: I also forgot to mention that the calling app is java, but the web service is C#. I don't think the shared assembly would work between these two platforms right?

Answer (score 0):

Just send what you want:

```
public class Whatever
{
    public int SkuNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
public void TakeList(List<Whatever> theList)
{
    foreach (var w in theList)
    {
    }
}
```